# Crear paquetes TCP en Python

Tags: python

Necesito crear paquetes TCP a partir de un fichero de log de apache en Python. Para ello, obtengo del log de apache la petición HTTP y la pongo como payload para el paquete en cuestión. Con los paquetes creados, creo un fichero PCAP que contiene todos los paquetes y lo analizo con Snort.

He intentado crear los paquetes con Scapy de la siguiente forma:

```
packet = IP(dst=dst_ip)/TCP(dport=9999)/Raw(load=payload)
```

Al analizar el fichero PCAP que contiene todos los paquetes creados me da siempre la misma alerta para cada paquete:

```
[**] [129:2:1] Data on SYN packet [**]
[Classification: Generic Protocol Command Decode] [Priority: 3] 
09/01-20:29:50.816860 127.0.0.1:20 -> 127.0.0.1:9999
TCP TTL:64 TOS:0x0 ID:1 IpLen:20 DgmLen:102
******S* Seq: 0x0  Ack: 0x0  Win: 0x2000  TcpLen: 20
[Xref => http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/34429][Xref => http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=2009-1157]
```

Este error supongo que es porque no estaba establecido el número de secuencia ni el ACK (3 way handshake) así que tuve que adaptar el código para crear el paquete:

```
ip = IP(src=src_ip, dst=dst_ip)
packet = (ip / TCP(sport=src_port, dport=dest_port, flags='PA',
      seq=seq_n, ack=ack_n) / Raw(load=fullrequest[0])

seq_n = seq_n + len(payload.encode('UTF8'))
```

De esta manera ya sí que hay secuencia pero cambia la alerta de Data on SYN packet por otra (aunque en vez de salir tantas alertas como el mismo número de paquetes, solo el 22% de los paquetes están mal):

```
[**] [129:12:1] Consecutive TCP small segments exceeding threshold [**]
[Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] 
09/01-20:49:15.037299 127.0.0.1:60664 -> 127.0.0.1:80
TCP TTL:64 TOS:0x0 ID:1 IpLen:20 DgmLen:94
***AP*** Seq: 0x156E7  Ack: 0xB  Win: 0x2000  TcpLen: 20
```

Al final, he optado por crearme una estructura cliente-servidor con sockets, analizar el tráfico con WireShark y después salvar los paquetes como PCAP. El problema aquí es que, además de que no puedo automatizar esta operación de análisis, Snort no detecta ni un solo ataque.

Los ataques son peticiones HTTP de la siguiente forma:

```
"GET /shoutbox.php?conf=../../../../../../../../etc/passwd HTTP/1.1"
"GET /cgi-bin/apexec.pl?etype=odp&template=../../../../../../../../../../etc/hosts%00.html&passurl=/category/ HTTP/1.1"
```

¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal? ¿Algún consejo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se ha resuelto aquí:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193036/analyzing-apache-log-with-snort

Básicamente, en lugar de intentar crear un fichero PCAP, utilizo la librería `requests` de Python para lanzar directamente las peticiones.